# What happens to bought items when you regenerate in Titanfall 2?

Tags: titanfall-2

When you regenerate in Titanfall 2, you go back to level 1 and all items that you unlocked will be locked until you reach that certain level again. I was wondering, when you regenerate, will the items that you bought (with credits) be locked? I was considering whether to buy Phase Shift, but I did not want to lose it and have to buy it again when I regenerated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, **all items unlocked with credits stay unlocked even after regenerating.**

I suggest buying whatever sounds interesting to you and those weapons / skills which are generally regarded as "all-around-good" like the Titans, phase shift and stim. From my own experience: Around generation 3-5 you will have enough credits and bought most of the things you could possibly want.